Indian Tax Schedule FA - assets in foreign retirement accounts
Suppose one has foreign retirement accounts (eg. IRA, Roth IRA, 401k in USA); and one has submitted form 10EE (Rule 21AAA) to defer taxation to withdrawal time. Should one still declare assets therein under Schedule FA?

Form 10EE is indepedent of Schedule FA requirement.Even if you filed Form 10EE if you are a ROR you need to declare foreign incomes & assets in Schedule FSI & FA respectively. Also include them in Schedule AL if total income > INR 50 lacs.

You mean Schedule FA rather than AL?

Sorry I misunderstood it as Schedule AL question. Have corrected it now. Thanks for pointing out.
